# Laravel 7 how to perform a query sql with join in mongoDB

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, mongodb

I have 2 databases(one in mySql and the other one in MongoDB) in my project and I need to perform a query like this

```php
public function getPosts() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $follow = DB::connection("mongodb")
    ->collection("followers")
    ->where("user_id", $user->id)->get();
    /*$res = DB::select("
    SELECT * 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE user_id = ? OR user_id IN 
        (SELECT user_id from $follows) 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC", [$user->id, $user->id]);

*/
    return response()->json($res);
}
```

This is a query which returns the posts from the logged user and from people the user follow
The followers table (the one in MongoDB) contains "user_id" and "follows_id"
The commented line is the original query (every table in one single database on mySql

Thank you

Edit: I solved through a query in mongodb, then I edited the result to get an array which I incorporated into the sql query through orWhereIn 
Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: MongoDB uses NoSQL, the "join" word does not make sense in this language.

Comment: And is there a way to perform that between the 2 databases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so... you may try a true multimodel database such as Oracle XE (it's free) to achieve your goal here...